# Sentry issue not unminifying code with uploaded source maps

Tags: reactjs, webpack, sentry, source-maps, sentryreact

I'm working on a ReactJS (create-react-app) project.

I do not generate source maps in my production build. But I still want to be able to unminify code for issues in production. In an attempt to achieve this I know create releases and uploade source maps, js and css code to a specific release and dist in Sentry (using sentry-cli).

```
export SENTRY_ORG=<org slug>
export SENTRY_PROJECT=<project name>
export SENTRY_RELEASE=<release>
export SENTRY_DIST=<dist>
sentry-cli releases new "$SENTRY_RELEASE"
sentry-cli releases set-commits "$SENTRY_RELEASE" --auto
sentry-cli releases finalize "$SENTRY_RELEASE"

sentry-cli sourcemaps inject --org $SENTRY_ORG --project $SENTRY_PROJECT --release $SENTRY_RELEASE ./build
sentry-cli sourcemaps upload --org $SENTRY_ORG --project $SENTRY_PROJECT --release $SENTRY_RELEASE --dist $SENTRY_DIST --strip-prefix / ./build
```

I can see that a new version is created in sentry and that the artifacts are attached to the release (1 css file, 1 js file, 1 js.map file). When an issue occurs in production, the issue is linked to the correct version and dist, **BUT** code is still not minified.

I suspect it is because I do two separate builds (one build with source maps and another build without). But there must be a way to connect them as the code is the same.

If I include the source maps in the production build, everything works as expected.

I have also tried only doing one build (with source maps), where I first uploaded it to sentry and then deleted source map and ref to source map and use the build as production build. I also tried changing the sourceMappingUrl to the artifact path in sentry (~/static/js/<name>.js.map). Nothing worked.

So my question is: How can I unminify code in sentry when my production build does not have sourcemaps?

Answer (score 0):

When you run the `sourcemaps inject` command you modify your bundles. You need to deploy the files that you ran the `sourcemaps inject` command on, otherwise the SDK cannot assign debug IDs to the error stack frames.